# Binding enum in combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5

`enter code here`Given this exmample:

```
  Public Enum Gender
   Masculine
   Femenine
  End Enum

public class ViewModel

private _gender as Gender

    Public Property Gender() As Gender
      Get
        Return _gender 
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Gender)
        _gender = value
      End Set
    End Property

end class

 Private Sub Form_Load


 cmbGender.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Enums.Sexo)) //combobox shows gender ok
 cmbGender.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedItem",ViewModel , "Gender", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

end sub
```

`Combobox` use `ViewModel` getter to set its `SelectedItem` as soon as the `Databindings.Add` executes but never use the setter when `SelectedItem` change in the User Interface.

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Sriram Sakthivel to enlighten me and check combobox events. The final situation is:

Using `SelectedItem`, `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation` and `combobox.causesValidation = true` works when `LostFocus` raises. If you need `onPropertyChanged` you should use `SelectedIndex` and the Sriram Sakthivel's code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be updated in `LostFocus` event of `ComboBox` because `SelectedItem` doesn't raise change notification (which is necessary for immediate update).

As a workaround you can use `SelectedIndex` property, which publishes change notification via `SelectedIndexChanged` event. But there is a problem, `SelectedIndex` is of type `Int32` you need to convert it to `Gender` and vice versa.

Here's how you'll do that: C# version

```
private void SetupBinding()
{
    var binding = new Binding("SelectedIndex", model, "Gender", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    binding.Format += binding_Format;
    binding.Parse += binding_Parse;
    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
}

void binding_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType == typeof(Gender))
    {
        e.Value = comboBox1.Items[(int)e.Value];
    }
}

void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType == typeof(int))
    {
        e.Value = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(e.Value);
    }
}
```

Am poor in Vb.net. So I used [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert it to vb.net from c#.

```
Private Sub SetupBinding()
    Dim binding = New Binding("SelectedIndex", model, "Gender", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    AddHandler binding.Format, AddressOf binding_Format
    AddHandler binding.Parse, AddressOf binding_Parse
    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding)
End Sub

Private Sub binding_Parse(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.DesiredType = GetType(Gender) Then
        e.Value = comboBox1.Items(CInt(e.Value))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub binding_Format(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.DesiredType = GetType(Integer) Then
        e.Value = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(e.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot to check combobox events and no event for SelectedItemChanged. My mind is a mess becase the awfull and spagetti legacy code I am refactoring.

Comment: Allow me ask you another little question: cmbGender.SelectedValue returs a Enum ok but DataBindings.Add with SelectedValue launch NullReferenceException in System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value). Do you know why?

Comment: @jlvaquero I tried that, It seems you can't Bind to `SelectedValue` when `ValueMember` property is empty. I get some exception like that, that's why I used `SelectedIndex` property. Otherwise, `SelectedValue` is the way to go. If you found how to bind to `SelectedValue` property please let me know.. thanks.